# Typescript interface accepts wrong type

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm new to Typescript. I'm stuck at the interfaces part. Using Nodejs I send an object from the client to the server called `startData`. This object contains an ID and Username. I'm using an interface to define the types in this object. I define testId as a number and Username as a string.

However, when I send for example testId as a string and Username as an object, no error gets thrown. Why does the interface accept the wrong types? I would expect it to throw some kind of unexpected type error.

```
interface startDataInterface{
    testId: number;
    username: string;
}

socket.on('startData', function(startData: startDataInterface) {
   ...
```

I'm sending this on the client:

```
socket.emit('startData', {testId: "string", username: {}});
```

Answer (score 1):

The socket method `on` only accepts generic functions, so `typescript` will not report an error on the receiving side.  Extend or delegate socket and write a typesafe wrapper if you need that degree of type checking.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably extending EventEmitter, which, by default has `any` for it's `emit` arguments.

Anytime `any` is used, typechecking effectively is disabled. By default there's also no relationship between what was emitted and what was caught with `on`.

It's possible to create very specific `on` and `emit` method, via overloading. For instance, you can define your `emit` method as such:

```
emit: function(eventName: 'startData', startData: StartDataInterface);
emit: function(eventName: string...args: any) {
}
```

With a signature like this, typescript will know how to enforce these types for the `startData` event, but you will also have to add the same type of overloaded signature on the `on` method.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Why are you using two emit functions here to catch one message?

Comment: @P.Yntema they are not 2 functions. It's one function with multiple overloaded definitions. Take a look at the official documentation (search for overloads on this page) https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html